# My Visual Studio takes All integer, long variable value as hexadecimal

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have a problem regarding my visual studio 2005. I initialized an integer variable and attach debugger to it to check its value at run time. When I run the application, the value of variable it shows is hexadecimal equivalent to value initialized.

How can change it to show in decimal?

Thank you

Answer (score 19):

Right-click on the value (such as in the "Locals" panel) and uncheck "Hexadecimal Display".

Answer (score 8):

Right-click the value in the viewer, select the menu item labelled "Hexadecimal Display", and remove the checkmark.

Comment: For immediate windows also you need to uncheck "Hexadecimal Display" from "Locals" panel or "Watch"